# Synchronizing queue in Java on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I understand the concept of synchronizing, but I'm now sure about why is it implemented that way, so I need a little help in here:

I have 2 threads:

`PeriodicalThread` will receive data periodically (let's say each 5 seconds) and put it in a `Queue` (using `ArrayDeque` for the moment, but I don't know if any other `Queue` implementation will work better)

`ProccessThread` will constantly check on the `Queue` to see if it is empty. If it is not empty, it will process the data **(FIFO)**.

So, at first my implementation would be:

```
// Both threads are inner class so they have access to Queue

private Queue queue;
private boolean isReadyToProccess;


class PeriodicalThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
           if(isNewDataAvailable) {
                // create Data object
                queue.add(data);
           }
        }
    }
}

class ProcessThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
           if(!queue.isEmpty() && isReadyToProccess) {
               Data data = queue.poll();
               processData(data);
           }
        }
    }
}

private void processData(Data data) {
    // this method send data over network, and the server response callback
    // changes isReadyToProcess value to true.
}
```

Then when wanting to handle **synchronization**, I wouldn't know If I should use a `lock` object (and how is it implemented) or if there is already a package `Queue` implementation that is thread-safe (because of the `add()` and `poll()` methods)

**Edit:** I forgot about the flag `isReadyToProcess` indicating next queue `Data` object is... well, ready to be proccessed. This flag should be synchronized also.

Comment: Look into `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: How does a boolean flag tell you something about the next object in the queue?  What if there are many objects in the queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ArrayDeque` doesn't support concurrency. Instead, use a real queue that supports concurrent work like [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and one of its implementations in `java.util.concurrent` package. I recommend using [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

In case you need to share flags between your threads, it would be better using [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of manually synchronizing a primitive `boolean` field.

Note: if you will work with concurrent process, it is better to work with classes provided by [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package that already support lock and synchronization out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation

This provides the functionality out of box which you are looking for. Thats why its best suited for producer consumer examples.

Here is an example

```
public class BlockingQueueExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1024);

        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();

        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
}


public class Producer implements Runnable{

    protected BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            queue.put("1");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            queue.put("2");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            queue.put("3");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    protected BlockingQueue queue = null;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(queue.take());
            System.out.println(queue.take());
            System.out.println(queue.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I don't know what a _raw_ BlockingQueue is, but the example above uses an ArrayBlockingQueue.

Comment: @jameslarge [Java Tutorials. Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at ArrayBlockingQueue and another BlockingQueue implementations.

From documentation:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

An alternative is also the ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

You can read more about concurrent Queues here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Answer (score 1):

Before Java 5 you'd have to implement a wait/notify mechanism. Since Java 5 you can use an implementation of the BlockingQueue interface for producer/consumer problems.

Take a look at this:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_producer_consumer.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use java Blocking Queue or Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>()), I like Collections.synchronized... as it is effectively making your collection thread safe and you are not bothering about locks and flags and similar stuff... just writing logical readable code.

LinkedList will provide you addFirst() addLast() and ofcourse getFirst(), getLast() to implement FIFO or LIFO behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Apache Common Collections library includes a [`SynchronizedQueue`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/SynchronizedQueue.html) class that can make any custom `Queue` implementation thread-safe.

`SynchronizedQueue.synchronizedQueue(new MyAwesomeNonThreadSafeQueue()`